# Angular 7 | Post to Google Form

Tags: angular, post, google-sheets, frontend, google-forms

I Want to create a really simple subscription for mailing list for a static website on github pages, which means I have no backend.

I thought I could do this using Google Sheets API but I have trouble getting it done on my angualr application.

What I have done so far is to create a google form with only one entry field (the email). I also have the entry number by inspecting it.

I tried to do it using jQuery ajax but it wont work..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont have idea about Google Sheets Api, but you can use firebase for recording your form data from the form. And you can host your form page in GithubPages/Firebase. It's very easy to use firebase.

Give it a try.

Hope it solves your query

Comment: I thought about using Firebase but I have never used it before and I was a little bit lazy so i tried to find an easiest way :p I will give it a try though since you also said so

Comment: Simple as hell! will check out Firebase more. Thanks for the motivation <3